# Difference between 2 datasets

Tags: dataset, dataiku

Hi I've a two Datasets called A and B. A is having 100 records and B is having 99 records. How to find the missed record in Dataiku tool?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do that. The best method depends on many factors: can you code? do you need to do this once or multiple times? etc.

Here is one solution I'm thinking of:

- Click on the dataset with 100 records
- Create a "Join with..." recipe
- Select the dataset with 99 records
- Under the "Join" tab, make sure that your "Left join" key is right
- Under the "Selected Columns" tab, select your join key
- Add prefix to the columns of the second dataset
- Run the recipe
- Open the resulting dataset and find the row for which the prefixed column is empty